# How to create a loop that should repeatedly prompt the user to type blast, punch, or kick for an attack or Do It! to exit the loop

Tags: java

Make a Player class with instance variables for name, attack, defense, and health. Make a parameterized constructor for it.  Make a method that will recieve an attack as a parameter and caclulate a new value for health if the damage ends up being greater than the health, set the damage to 0.  The defense will decrease the amount of damage taken.  Make an attack method that will ask the user for an attack.  They can choose blast, punch, or kick each with a different attack value.  Every time that a choice is made,  more value will be added to the attack.  When the user enters Do It!, return the value of attack.

Create another class that will contain the main method.  In that method, create two Player objects using the parameterized constructor and have one player attack the the other.  When run, it should repeatedly prompt the user to type blast, punch, or kick for an attack or Do It! to exit the loop.  It should display a message that says what the player's new health is after the attack.  If the player recieved 0 damage due to the attack being overpowered, tell the user this.  You will need to make another method to pull this off.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MakeAClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String sentence = input.nextLine();
            if (sentence.equals("Blast"))
            {

            }

      }

        //Player 
        class Person
        {
         private String name;
         private int health;
         private int defense;
         private int attack;

         //Player Base Stats
         public Person()
         {
           String name= "alex";
           int health= 100;
           int defense= 70;
           int attack= 10;
         } 

         //Player Stats
         public Person(String name, int health, int defense, int attack)
         {
           this.name=name;
           this.health=health;
           this.defense=defense;
           this.attack=attack;
         }

         //Attack Damage
         public int attack(int attack)
         {  
            this.attack=attack;
            return attack;
         }

         //Damage Taken
         public void takeDamage(int attack)
         {
           this.health=this.health-(this.attack-this.defense);
           if (this.health > 0)
           {
           System.out.println(this.health);
           }
           else {
               System.out.print("0");
           }           
           }

        }

}
```

no error messages in code but don't know how to finish what is required

Comment: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be to research a bit on game loops.

As much as you may want it to happen, **no one here will answer you if you are just going to give us homework problems.**

**StackOverflow is not a homework service** and should not be used as such. It's for asking questions that will result in you actually learning something about programming.

A lot of programming is not actually typing out the code but instead researching the logic behind whatever it is that you are writing.